# m2m_changed signal with many-to-many through - save

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-signals

I have these two basic models,

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, default=0)
    ...
```

and

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, blank=True, through='CartItem')
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    def recalculate_and_save(self):
      print("recalculate_and_save running")
      total = 0
      for ci in self.cartitem_set.all():
          total += ci.product.price*ci.quantity
      self.total = total
      self.save()
```

, and a helper model for many-to-many relation above, to account for quantity:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

What I want to achieve is automatic calculation of Cart's total every time an item is added or removed. So,

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=CartItem)
def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"m2m_changed received; action={action}, instance={instance}")
    instance.recalculate_and_save()
```

Then I realized, seeing pre_save and post_save actions in logs, that I'm likely doing something wrong - calling save in the function which is called (twice) from parent's save, as per docs. The first question is, then - why doesn't it send me into an infinite loop? And the second (and probably more important) - why am I only seeing the receiver function executing on removing items from the cart, but not on adding them? Removing is done via

> cart.products.remove(product_obj)

, but adding via

> cart_obj.cartitem_set.add(cart_item_obj, bulk=False)

, which is probably related to why removal triggers the receiver, while adding does not. But that complicates the question even more - having sender set to be CartItem, I would expect removal, performed on product, to miss the receiver, not adding, which works on cartitems directly (though removal of products removes CartItems too, through the on_delete=CASCADE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m2m_changed` signal will be triggered when modifying a `ManyToManyField` (`products` in this case).

From the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

```
Sent when a ManyToManyField is changed on a model instance
```

So for your questions:

---

> why doesn't it send me into an infinite loop?

This is because `recalculate_and_save` didn't do anything with the m2m field `products`, so it won't trigger the `m2m_changed` signal again avoiding the infinite loop.

---

> why am I only seeing the receiver function executing on removing items from the cart, but not on adding them?

Since the signal will only come from when modifying `products`, doing things with `cartitem_set` will not trigger it.

So you need to manually call `recalculate_and_save` after modifying `cartitem_set`:

```
cart_obj.cartitem_set.add(cart_item_obj, bulk=False)
cart_obj.recalculate_and_save()
```

Comment: thanks mate, that demystifies a few things. I suppose the fact that I have to specify a sender make it look as if the signals are more "liberal" with their triggers.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, since it's to the point and unblocked me, but it feels like a hack - signals are praised because they "decouple" the components, and here I have to manually call the recalculate_and_save. What's even more confusing, logging sender inside this receiver does show it to be <class 'carts.models.CartItem'> (even though removing the product from the Cart doesn't work on CartItem level, just nukes the product model).

Comment: I can relate! I think it might help to remember that for this particular signal, it's concerned with the field rather than the model itself, so it's purpose seems to be just that.